# Xamarin iOS < 11

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios10

I am trying to get just a "hello world" single view iOS app running on an iOS 10 simulator but it just immediately crashes/exits out of the program, it does not even appear to hit the entry point of the app. Any thoughts?

I've tried using
 -- Visual Studio 2019 (Windows 10 paired to mac -- mojave)
 -- Visual Studio directly on the mac.

Running the same app on anything 11.0 and greater works as expected.

The version of xcode on the mac is 10.2.1, mac is mojave 10.14.4.

Comment: i _think_ i just found a work around... appears to be a simulator issue... https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/5888 ... working to verify now

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/5888#issuecomment-482133467) the described workaround:

> Workaround: change the `Linker behavior` in the iOS project's Build options to `Link Framework SDKs only` *and* add `--registrar:static` to the additional mtouch arguments in the same Build options page.

solves the issue.